# Serial- / Socket IO and GCC nothrow attribute

Tags: c, gcc, io, mingw

I have functions which abstract *serial-* and *socket IO* (Linux / Windows) implemented in C.
All of them are marked as `extern "C"` because they may get called from C++ as well.

Is it safe to use `__attribute__((__nothrow__))` (or MinGW Macro `__MINGW_NOTHROW`) here / can i assume no exceptions are thrown?

**Called functions - Sockets:**
*(not all additions for WinSock listed)*

- `socket`
- `connect`
- `send` / `recv`
- `close` (`closesocket` on Windows)
- `sendto` / `recvfrom`

**Called functions - Serial:**
*Since serial IO code differs to much between windows / linux not all are listed here*

- *Linux (GNU)*

  - `open`
  - `tcgetattr`
  - `read` / `write`
  - `close`
- *Windows (MinGW)*

  - `CreateFile`
  - `GetCommState` / `SetCommTimeouts`
  - `ReadFile` / `WriteFile`
  - `CloseHandle`

Since *ANSI C* has no exceptions (please correct me if I'm wrong) they won't be thrown, but how about GCC extensions and OS API calls?

Documentation: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html (see `nothrow`).

Comment: If you are writing your code in C (and not C++), why do you bother about exceptions? There is nothing you can do with them anyway.

Comment: This will allow GCC to do some optimisations. However i don't want to create trouble if called from C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C

GNU C (Linux) uses `__THROW` macro instead of `__MINGW_NOTHROW`.
While the MinGW one is `__nothrow__` attribute only, `__THROW` contains `__leaf__` attribute too.

### C++

If you use C++, `__THROW` has another meaning: `throw()` - indicating that no exception is thrown (analog to `__nothrow__`; but defined in the C++ standard).

So it depends on whether you **compile** with C or C++, not on what you call the functions from (*GNU C / C++ only!*).

**Example:**

```
void f() __THROW;
```

Treated as ...

**GNU C:**

```
void f() __attribute__((__nothrow__, __leaf__))
```

**GNU C++:**

```
void f() throw()
```

Functions<sup>1)</sup> which are *cancellation points*, therefore **not marked** with
   `__THROW`:

- `open()`
- `read()`
- `write()`
- `close()`
- `connect()`
- `send()`
- `recv()`
- `close()`
- `sendto()`
- `recvfrom()`

Functions<sup>1)</sup> **marked** with `__THROW`:

- `tcgetattr()`
- `socket()`

At least, these are save to `__nothrow__`.

In contrast, **MinGW doesn't differ** C from C++; in both cases the attribute is set.

Using example from above, `__nothrow__` is set on C *and* C++:

```
void f() __attribute((__nothrow__))
```

Functions<sup>1)</sup> **not marked** with `__MINGW_NOTHROW`:

- `socket()`
- `connect()`
- `send()`
- `recv()`
- `closesocket()`
- `sendto()`
- `recvfrom()`
- `CreateFile()`
- `GetCommState()`
- `SetCommTimeouts()`
- `ReadFile()`
- `WriteFile()`
- `CloseHandle()`

To make it short: **none!**

> ### Compatibility
>
> #### With C
>
> C language code that is expecting to interoperate with C++ should be
>   compiled with -fexceptions. This will make debugging a C language
>   function called as part of C++-induced stack unwinding possible.
>
> In particular, unwinding into a frame with no exception handling data
>   will cause a runtime abort. If the unwinder runs out of unwind info
>   before it finds a handler, std::terminate() is called.
>
> Please note that most development environments should take care of
>   getting these details right. For GNU systems, all appropriate parts of
>   the GNU C library are already compiled with -fexceptions.

<sub>( source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html )</sub>

So compiling with `-fexceptions` and there's no need for equivalent attribute. If you only can mark specific functions you have to / should use `__nothrow__`.

But while using `__nothrow__` attribute looks save only on GNU C++, and some functions of GNU C on Linux, it's not that clear on Windows.

---

#### Addendum:

To avoid some parts of this problem, i've written a macro similar to `__THROW` but usable on MinGW too:

```
#if defined __GNUC__
    #ifndef __THROW
        #ifdef  __cplusplus
            #define __THROW         throw()
        #else
            #define __THROW         __attribute__((__nothrow__))
        #endif
    #endif
#else
    #define __THROW
#endif
```

*Note:* `__leaf__` is not included.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Talking only about those which are listed on my question.*

Answer (score 1):

take care of gcc version, `nothrow` has been introduced with gcc 3.3!

you can port `__THROW` from `sys/cdefs.h` to mingw:

```
/* skip this entire part on linux (= glibc available)*/
#if defined __GNUC__ && !defined __linux__

/********* port __GNUC_PREREQ macro to mingw *********/
# if !defined __GNUC_PREREQ

# if !defined __MINGW_H
#  include <_mingw.h>
#  define __GNUC_PREREQ(major, minor)       __MINGW_GNUC_PREREQ(major, minor)
# else
#  if defined (__GNUC_MINOR__)
#   define __GNUC_PREREQ(major, minor)      __GNUC__ > (major) || (__GNUC__ == (major) && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= (minor)))
#  else
#   define __GNUC_PREREQ(major, minor)      0
#  endif
# endif 

#endif /* __GNUC_PREREQ */


/********* from gnu c blirary *********/

/* All functions, except those with callbacks or those that
   synchronize memory, are leaf functions.  */
# if __GNUC_PREREQ (4, 6) && !defined _LIBC
#  define __LEAF , __leaf__
#  define __LEAF_ATTR __attribute__ ((__leaf__))
# else
#  define __LEAF
#  define __LEAF_ATTR
# endif

/* GCC can always grok prototypes.  For C++ programs we add throw()
   to help it optimize the function calls.  But this works only with
   gcc 2.8.x and egcs.  For gcc 3.2 and up we even mark C functions
   as non-throwing using a function attribute since programs can use
   the -fexceptions options for C code as well.  */
# if !defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (3, 3)
#  define __THROW       __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ __LEAF))
#  define __THROWNL     __attribute__ ((__nothrow__))
#  define __NTH(fct)    __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ __LEAF)) fct
# else
#  if defined __cplusplus && __GNUC_PREREQ (2,8)
#   define __THROW      throw ()
#   define __THROWNL    throw ()
#   define __NTH(fct)   __LEAF_ATTR fct throw ()
#  else
#   define __THROW
#   define __THROWNL
#   define __NTH(fct)   fct
#  endif
# endif

#else   /* Not GCC.  */

# define __inline       /* No inline functions.  */

# define __THROW
# define __THROWNL
# define __NTH(fct) fct

#endif  /* GCC.  */
```

see [glibc - sys/cdefs.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=misc/sys/cdefs.h;hb=HEAD) for full code.

*edit:* `__GNUC_PREREQ` can be replaced with `__MINGW_GNUC_PREREQ(major, minor)`, then you don't have to redifine it as above.